# How to limit device usage on Android Market (new feature)?

Tags: compatibility, google-play, android

Market has added device compatibility check.Now we can check if an app will work on specific device, for exaple HTC mobile phone, Samsung Galaxy, etc.

What about developer's side: How can we build apps for specific devices only or restrict app for tablets only? How to do restriction in XML and code? It's probably some attribute in Manifest file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Market checks this out by itself.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html) "Specifying Your Application's System API Requirements" ?

Comment: Hm, I see only min/max/target... parameters. Nothing about restrictions by specific devices.

Comment: You mean specific devices by brand and model?

Comment: Yes. I think it is supported now.